# Google Token has been expired or revoked

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-api, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to implement an app that will remind the user on his upcoming google calendar events. I have created google OAuth token successfully and my app was working fine. but suddenly i got this error "error: 'invalid_grant',error_description: 'Token has been expired or revoked.'".
Here is my code:

```
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

const googleConfig = {
  clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 
  clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
  redirect: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/landingPage' 
};

function createConnection() {
  return new OAuth2(
    googleConfig.clientId,
    googleConfig.clientSecret,
    googleConfig.redirect
  );
}

const defaultScope = [
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
];

function getConnectionUrl(auth) {

  return auth.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    prompt: 'consent', // access type and approval prompt will force a new refresh token to be made each time signs in
    scope: defaultScope

  });
}

function urlGoogle() {
  const auth = createConnection(); // this is from previous step
  const url = getConnectionUrl(auth);
  return url;
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    const url = urlGoogle()
    return res.render("index", { loginLink: url });
});

 app.get('/landingPage', (req, res) => {
    const OAuth = createConnection()
    function getNewToken(OAuth) {
      OAuth.getToken(req.query.code, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
        OAuth.setCredentials(token);
        fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
          if (err) return console.error(err);
          console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
          callHFunction(OAuth)
        });
      });
      }
      // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return getNewToken(OAuth);
      OAuth.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
      console.log(OAuth.credentials)
      callHFunction(OAuth)
    });
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./landingPage.html"));
  });
```

Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: have you checked if Token has been expired or revoked? It's your token, so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common cause for

> error: 'invalid_grant'

- the user revoked your access.
- you have reached the maximum number of outstanding refresh tokens (50)  makes sure to always store the newest.
- your app is still in the testing phase. Refresh tokens expire after 7 - 14 days.

In the event you get this error its best to make sure your application can handle it by prompting the user to authorize your application again.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reset token. [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmHSv.png)

Just delete this token.json like in image and then,

1. Open Google Account Settings.
2. Go to Security Tab.
3. Manage Third Party Applications.
4. Delete the google application if present else skip this part.

That's it now, go to your application make a request, paste code, new token file is generated.

Comment: This is the most succinct, direct answer